# Change display order of View block in Content area of page

Tags: 7, theming

I have a dynamic view block that is set to display in "content" region of a Basic page. The Basic page has a field that i want to display at the bottom (i.e. after view block)
Question: I cannot figure out how to change display order, so that page displays View block first, then a field from Basic page. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [Field as Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock):

> Field as Block provides an easy way to display one or more fields of the current node in a block.